# ASP.NET MVC4 - Hidden field validation not clearing after value is set

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a hidden field on my form that is required.  The hidden field is populated when a user selects a value from a textbox using jQuery UI autocomplete.  I have setup my form validator to not ignore hidden fields so that the validation actually works.  The validation does work, but when a user selects the desired option from the autocomplete, which then populates the hidden field, the validation message will not clear and will show until the form is posted.  Do I need to manually call `$('form').validate()` or something once the hidden field gets set or is there a way to have this clear without any extra javascript code?

My View Model:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SchoolId { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
@model IndexViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SchoolName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SchoolName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SchoolId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SchoolId)
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
}

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // stop validator from ignoring hidden fields
            var validator = $('form').data('validator');
            validator.settings.ignore = "";

            // schoolname autocomplete
            $('#SchoolName').autocomplete({
                minLength: 1,
                source: [
                    { label: "ABC University", value: "1" },
                    { label: "Oklahoma University", value: "2" },
                    { label: "Texas University", value: "3" }
                ],
                select: function (e, ui) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('#SchoolId').val(ui.item.value);
                    $('#SchoolName').val(ui.item.label);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit**

Sparky, here is the rendered HTML:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="SchoolName">SchoolName</label>
        <input id="SchoolName" name="SchoolName" type="text" value="" />
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SchoolId must be a number." data-val-required="The SchoolId field is required." id="SchoolId" name="SchoolId" type="hidden" value="" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="SchoolId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790478/client-side-validation-not-working-for-hidden-field-in-asp-net-mvc-3) would help you.

Comment: You should be showing us the _rendered_ HTML of the form as seen by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the error message remains is because there are none of the normal validation triggers on a hidden field.  Normally, for a single field, validation is triggered on key-up or on blur.  The field is hidden so only the submit button will trigger a validation test of the hidden field when the whole form is validated.

However, you can programatically trigger a validation test on any field by calling the `.valid()` method at any time.

```
$('input[name="field"]').valid();  // force validation of 'input name="field"'
```

Here is a crude jsFiddle demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/LJzfu/

- Click 'submit' to show the "required" message on the hidden input called `field2`, which has no value.
- Clicking the "go" button programatically puts a value in the hidden input.  The form would now technically pass validation (upon submit) but the error message remains because we have no validation trigger.
- Trigger validation by calling `.valid()` immediately after putting a value in the hidden field.  This forces a validation test of the hidden field, which then hides the error message (as long as the validation rules are satisfied).

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Wasn't sure what method to call, so thank you for pointing me in the right direction!